# Why does unsharing mount namespace require CAP_SYS_ADMIN?

Tags: linux, unshare

For a project of mine I need **only** the mount namespace unshared, which requires the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability (see [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html)). While it is possible to create a new mount-namespace without capabilities by unsharing the user namespace as well, I would like to avoid that, since this introduces other limitations (e.g. setuid-programs cannot be called from there). I'm thinking about writing a setuid-program which allows unsharing the mountspace for everyone and was wondering, if that is insecure in any way? Currently I cannot think up a scenario where that would be the case. So, what is the rationale behind disallowing unsharing the mountspace for regular users?

Comment: Because it may allow anyone to create mount namespace with mount points sharing a peer group with some mount point in the original mount namespace.

Comment: Could you please you elaborate, how exactly this could be a done? A regular user cannot create mountpoints without appropriate permissions...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons for the kernel choice.

1. If `/` has not been remounted as `MNT_SHARED` (for example by `systemd`), then cloning the mount namespace will pin all mounts, including of removable media.
2. Also, we don't allow unprivileged users to create "unexpected" states, because it has the potential to confuse some setuid program.  So this is the safer option, if they have no particular reason to think it would be useful.  And they could not think of any significant reason why you would want permission to clone a mount namespace, but not be able to *do* anything with it.  Clearly you have thought of some reason, but even reading your question I was not able to guess what it was :-).

Comment: What do you mean by "pin"

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 keep open, and prevent from unmounting.