# Allow a non-super-user run process to fork and clone itself (probably duplicate)

Tags: permissions, docker, non-root-user, clone

### Question

I would like to launch a Docker container which runs a process which may or may not clone itself.

Is it possible to set up a user with normal + clone_newuts permission so that I do not have a login user to my container which is a superuser?

Initially this question was labelled: `CLONE_NEWUTS permission only`, which is incorrect. @sourcejedi has answed in good faith below and improved my understanding considerably.

### EDIT-1

I've found where the su flags are held: `/usr/include/linux/sched.h`, I expect the answer to be something along the lines of monkey patching a specific users permissions on container create. I'm going to go along that route for now and see where it takes me.

### EDIT-2

I found where the user/file capabilities can be set. I see I have a lot of reading to do but I think that a specific permission (capability) can be given to a file (which will be excutable in this case). From the capabilities manpage:
`Starting with kernel 2.2, Linux divides the privileges traditionally associated with superuser into distinct units, known as capabilities, which can be independently enabled and disabled.  Capabilities are a per-thread attribute.`
so, it should be possible to apply a specific capability (whose flag is found in the above header) to either a file or user. Which one, I'm not sure yet but it's getting pretty fun and deep to find this out.

### EDIT-3

As @sourcejedi has pointed out I have misinterpreted my needs. The information neccessary is in `man limits.conf`, in which one may run a process at a specified user level, in this case `root`.

### EDIT-4

Unfortunately the route I have taken from EDIT-3 is also incorrect. This allows a specified user to run *all* processes at the specified uesr level. @sourcejedi is still correct, however I will open a new question asking what I really need. Link: [Run a single process that can fork and clone as a non-root-user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516055/run-a-single-process-that-can-fork-and-clone-as-a-non-root-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a capability to specifically allow calling clone() with the `CLONE_NEWUTS` flag.

`CLONE_NEWUTS` is used to create and enter a new "UTS namespace".  All of the namespace types require `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to create, with one exception:  The upstream Linux kernel allows unprivileged users to create and enter a new user namespace.

When you create a user namespace, you can allow yourself root / full capabilities *inside* that namespace, including `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`.  If your system supports this, you can see it with `unshare -r` .  It opens a root shell in a new user namespace.

**The intended method for unprivileged users to use namespaces, was inside a new user namespace.  However some Linux distributions configure the kernel to dis-allow this feature.**

`CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is used as a catchall for anything without a more specific capability. It is far too powerful.  You should assume it can be used to take over other programs and hence gain any other capability.[1]

The default configuration of the Docker daemon [does not place any container inside a new user namespace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#user-namespace-known-limitations).  As a result, you should assume that explicitly granting `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to a docker container allows it to escape the container with full privileges.[1]

If unprivileged users could create all the types of namespace directly, it would have raised issues where namespaces could be used to confuse a setuid program, into performing privileged actions that it was not supposed to.  Cross-reference: "[Why does unsharing mount namespace require CAP_SYS_ADMIN?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476847/why-does-unsharing-mount-namespace-require-cap-sys-admin/495839)"

The other option is to use a helper executable with setuid/capabilities which only allows a specific task.  Like how `sudo` can be configured to allow running specific privileged commands only.  This is the approach taken by [bubblewrap](https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap), which is used by FlatPak.

The bubblewrap README also provides some references, about the security concerns which caused Linux distributions to restrict user namespaces.

I think this story overlaps with the reasons that "Docker in Docker" is not really supported / is not possible without disabling important security features in the main Docker daemon.  Although it is not quite the same.

---

[1] For example `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is the capability used to mount block filesystems, which kernel developers consider are not possible to reliably secure against malicious FS images.

Inside a new user namespace, `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` does not allow you to mount block filesystems.  But, if you created a new mount namespace as well - e.g. `unshare -rm` - CAP_SYS_ADMIN will allow you to create bind mounts, mount the `proc` filesystem, and in kernerl 4.18 or above you can mount FUSE filesystems.

Docker also uses LSM-based security - SELinux or AppArmor - on systems where those are available.  It's possible these layers could restrict `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` in some ways.  This is much more obscure than Docker's other security layers.  If you relied on the detailed workings of specific LSMs, that seems to defeat one of the points of building a convenient portable Docker container.

Comment: But I can add the correct capability bits to the file (I think I have to set setuid and setpcap) on container build by the su, so I can add the bits to the file to run and not have an overpriv'd user or process. The file I am adding to _is_ the helper file you mention. However your suggestion to configure sudo maybe the best way. I will look into that. Thanks very much.

Comment: @MarkJL unless you [specifically configure](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) Docker, it does not use user namespaces.  Do not grant CAP_SYS_ADMIN to processes inside docker without very careful consideration, for example CAP_SYS_ADMIN is the capability used to mount block filesystems, which kernel developers consider are not possible to reliably secure against malicious FS images.  Inside a user namespace, CAP_SYS_ADMIN does not allow you to mount block filesystems.

Comment: My intent is only to give the process perms to fork and clone itself which does not require sys_admin caps. Thanks for the advice and links, I will implement the configuration and capabilities and see what I get.

Comment: @MarkJL CLONE_NEWUTS requires CAP_SYS_ADMIN.  (In the context of your current user namepace, whatever that is). Your question says you want to use CLONE_NEWUTS somewhere.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean there was a mistake in your question?

Comment: There is no mistake in the question, only a mistake in my understanding. I guess I wanted there to be a way to fork and clone without absolute power and I have been looking for it, hence not finding it as yet. I need CLONE_NEWUTS caps to clone a proc, so I guess I should be configuring sudo to only provide that capability?

Comment: Thanks @sourcejedi, you are correct I did ask the wrong question, however I've learnt a bunch of things and who doesn't like that? Thanks for your patience. I wish I could give you more points.

Comment: @MarkJL You don't need to use CLONE_NEWUTS if all you want to do is clone a process. It looks like I guessed wrong about what questions to ask you :-).  If you choose to ask a new question, you might try to include a little more redundancy - e.g. a reference for why you think CLONE_NEWUTS is required to call clone() - e.g. this can make it easier to distinguish when someone has a conceptual error, or when they are not writing very clearly because they are not very good with English :-).

Comment: It's because I want to make a mini-container within docker so I can spawn new procs off of it to deal with requests as they come in rather than have a continually loaded program in memory a bit like serverless.

Comment: Each of the programs should be running in their own space, isolated from the entrypoint program, which will be listening ready to spawn them off.

Comment: @MarkJL I edited the answer a little more. I think you will find the bubblewrap doc interesting, but this answer is still not positive about how to achieve your goal :-).

Comment: I believe bubble wrap security functionality is covered by `--security-opt=no-new-privileges` but I could be mistaken. I'm thinking the using a system user which is invoked as `CMD su -u systemuser ./command-to-run` in the docker file could work? This negates everything we said earlier though, a solution that works is what I need now - I have this working using sudo, I just feel uncomfortable with that user being accessible.

Comment: @MarkJL AFAIK you can't possibly have the code you linked code working unless you pass an option to docker that enables CAP_SYS_ADMIN in the container.  Because https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/ . I really don't want to do that much guesswork.  If you want me to comment on what you're doing, then tell me what you're doing.    If Docker is letting you clone() into a new namespace without using user namespaces, on a supported platform, then you have found some bug in Docker, you should not rely on it continuing to work, etc.

Comment: @MarkJL Docker does not really support nesting, as you can see from searching "docker in docker".  AFAICS, without user namespaces, the only solution is to drop Docker and have your program call out to bubblewrap or equivalent.  bubblewrap exists.  If that's inconvenient to deploy, your current sequence of code could easily be split up to use a minimal set-uid executable instead.  Just need to add a sequence to drop all privs again and execve() into a command passed as an argument.  Don't ask us how easy it is in Go tho, I don't know what the exact pitfalls are (including for security).

Comment: I really appreciate you spending time on this @sourcejedi! I trust you are correct, but I have one more thing to try. You were correct in your previous comment about it not working inside Docker, I had it working on my machine (expected, really) but I am like a dog with a bone right now. Just one final configuration to try before I stop. I _will_ be trying bubblewrap as soon as I have done this. It does seem that even with user namespaces configured docker will not fork and clone.

Comment: @MarkJL configuring Docker to use user namespaces is a way to make it safer when you enable CAP_SYS_ADMIN in the container.  That's the `--cap-add` option.  I think it should be able to work.

Comment: I have a long journey to go on, both in reality and in Linux sysadmin. I will get back to you once I have completed the former. This has been great fun (for me ;) ).